# Trouble with backslash characters and rsyslog writing to postgres

Tags: postgresql, rsyslog

I have rsyslog 4.6.4 configured to write mail logs to a PostgreSQL database.  It all works fine, until the log message contains a backslash, as in this example:

> Jun 12 11:37:46 dc5 postfix/smtp[26475]: Vk0nYDKdH3sI: to=<-----@----.--->, relay=----.---[---.---.---.---]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.77/0.07/0.3/0.35, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (host ----.---[---.---.---.---] said: 451 4.3.0 Error writing to file d:\pmta\spool\B\00000414, status = ERROR_DISK_FULL in "DATA" (in reply to end of DATA command))

The above is the log entry, as written to /var/log/mail.log. It is correct.  The trouble is that the backslash characters in the file name are interpreted as escapes when sent to the following SQL recipe:

```
$template dcdb, "SELECT rsyslog_insert(('%timereported:::date-rfc3339%'::TIMESTAMPTZ)::TIMESTAMP,'%msg:::escape-cc%'::TEXT,'%syslogtag%'::VARCHAR)",STDSQL
:syslogtag, startswith, "postfix" :ompgsql:/var/run/postgresql,dc,root,;dcdb
```

As a result, the `rsyslog_insert()` stored procedure gets the following value for as `msg`:

> Vk0nYDKdH3sI: to=<-----@----.--->, relay=----.---[---.---.---.---]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.77/0.07/0.3/0.35, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (host ----.---[199.85.216.241] said: 451 4.3.0 Error writing to file d:pmtaspoolB

The `\p`, `\s`, `\B` and `\0` in the file name are interpreted by PostgreSQL as literal `p`, `s`, and `B` followed by a NULL character, thus early-terminating the string. This behavior can be easiily confirmed with:

```
dc=# SELECT 'd:\pmta\spool\B\00000414';
   ?column?   
--------------
 d:pmtaspoolB
(1 row)

dc=#
```

Is there a way to correct this problem? Is there a way I'm not finding in the rsyslog docs to turn `\` into `\\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should ***REALLY*** be using parameterized queries & prepared statements when passing arbitrary strings.
(This probably isn't your fault -- rsyslog is almost certainly responsible for that horror).

If you can't switch to a better query structure the Postgres `encode` function can probably help you out ([see the documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)) -- Specify an encoding of `escape` and Postgres will conveniently double all your backslashes in the string you pass to it.

---

Note that if you're feeling particularly pedantic you can [enable `standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS), which makes Postgres treat the `\` character in a string as a literal backslash rather than its historical (unix-y) behavior of treating it as an escape character.
Whether such a change is viable in your environment depends on a lot of factors...

Comment: I tried your `encode()` suggestion, but the input is escape-processed too soon. The end result is the same.  `standard_conforming_strings` seems to be a reasonable solution. It's unfortunate that with rsyslog I can't just set that as a session variable. But in my case, it should work to make it system-wide without much fallout.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: To limit fallout I believe you can set it on a per-database level (`ALTER DATABASE foo SET standard_conforming_strings=true`) -- never tried this myself, but there's [a promising Postgres mailing list post about it](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2006-07/msg01007.php)